# IBM Worklight - How to use Custom Server URL?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

When you install a Worklight application onto an iPhone, in the settings there's a parameter "Custom Server URL" you can use to change the Worklight Server the app is to connect to.

I was wondering if there's such a parameter you can change on the fly on an Android device as well, or do I have to redeploy the application every time I want to change the server?

I was also wondering if it's possible to disable this feature? I'm thinking in a production scenario I probably don't want my users to be able to change the server they're pointing to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, [the Worklight Settings feature](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/dev/c_setting_page.html) is meant only for development time, and should (I would say even, **must**) **be turned off** when moving to production (if the intended end-user is the Public and not in-house employees where it may be useful for specific use cases...).

It is available for both (and only) Android and iOS in `application-descriptor.xml` in their respective environment nodes.
You need simply change its value from the default `true` to `false`.

- In iOS you access it from the Settings.app
- In Android you access it by tapping on the device's physical Menu button